# CrystalQuartz not working when running as windows service

Tags: c#, windows-services, console-application, scheduler, quartz.net

I have added crystal quartz in my quartz scheduler project to show the dashboard ([check link](https://github.com/guryanovev/CrystalQuartz)).
below code works fine when I am running the application as a console app. but it does not work when we deploy it as windows service on the same machine. it's not even throwing any exception nor any log in event logger.

```
IScheduler scheduler = SetupScheduler();
                Action<IAppBuilder> startup = app => 
                {
                    app.UseCrystalQuartz(scheduler);
                };

                Console.WriteLine("Starting self-hosted server...");
                using (WebApp.Start("http://localhost:9000/", startup))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Server is started");
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("Check http://localhost:9000/quartz to see jobs information");
                    Console.WriteLine();

                    Console.WriteLine("Starting scheduler...");
                    scheduler.Start();

                    Console.WriteLine("Scheduler is started");
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("Press [ENTER] to close");     
                    Console.ReadLine();     
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Shutting down...");
                scheduler.Shutdown(waitForJobsToComplete: true);
                Console.WriteLine("Scheduler has been stopped");
```

when we deploy the application as windows service I am getting below error while opening the link in the browser "This site can’t be reached". but its working fine when we run it as a console.

Comment: is there any difference between running as console and running as windows service?

Answer (score 0):

finally, I solved it by replacing console.readline to below code

```
System.Threading.ManualResetEvent ojbManualResetEvent = new System.Threading.ManualResetEvent(false);
                ojbManualResetEvent.WaitOne();
```